# Combinators in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

everyone! I am quite new to HTML and CSS. I learned about 2 weeks ago. On my final website, I wanted to add a drop-down menu at the top. I want that when I hover over the 'store' tab, the 'shopping cart' tab slides down. I want to do it in only CSS. How do I reference one HTML element from another one from CSS code? What is the difference between > + ~ and other combinators. Sample code:

```
#store > #shoppingCart{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, the symbols you mention are:

- `>` is the the child combinator;
- `+` is the adjacent sibling combinator;
- `~` is the general sibling combinator.

The difference between them is this:

`#store > .shoppingCart { background-color: red; }`

```
<div class=shoppingCart>This will not be targeted</div>
<div id=store>
  <div class=shoppingCart>This WILL be targeted</div>
  <div class=shoppingCart>This WILL ALSO be targeted</div>
  <div class=inner>
    <div class=shoppingCart>This will not be targeted</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=shoppingCart>This will not be targeted either</div>
<div class=shoppingCart>Neither will this</div>
```

The `>` combinator selects only direct child elements (elements directly underneath the first one) of the selector specified, so, in this case, only the one immediately underneath `#store`.

`#store + .shoppingCart { background-color: red; }`

```
<div class=shoppingCart>This will not be targeted</div>

<div id=store>
  <div class=shoppingCart>This will not be targeted</div>
  <div class=shoppingCart>This will not be targeted either</div>
  <div class=inner>
    <div class=shoppingCart>This will not be targeted either</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=shoppingCart>This WILL be targeted</div>
<div class=shoppingCart>But this one won't be</div>
```

The `+` combinator selects an element that is the immediate next sibling (elements that are on the same level, ie. next to one another) of the first element, so if there is a `.shoppingCart` that is a sibling after a `#store`, it will be selected - but only if that element is AFTER the first one; a previous sibling cannot be selected in this way.

`#store ~ .shoppingCart { background-color: red; }`

```
<div class=shoppingCart>This will not be targeted</div>

<div id=store>
  <div class=shoppingCart>This will not be targeted</div>
  <div class=shoppingCart>This will not be targeted either</div>
  <div class=inner>
    <div class=shoppingCart>This will not be targeted either</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=shoppingCart>This WILL be targeted</div>
<div class=shoppingCart>This WILL be targeted as well</div>
```

The `~` combinator selects an element that is any following sibling of the first element, so if there is a `.shoppingCart` that follows as a sibling of `#store`, it will be selected.

Comment: Your definitions of `+` and `~` are not quite correct: both only target siblings that come *after* the element selected by the first part of the combinator; the difference between the two is that `+` only selects the immediate next element (if it matches) whereas `~` selects any next elements (immediate or otherwise). There are no combinators to select arbitrary (previous or next) kinds of siblings.

Comment: You're absolutely right, of course.  I don't know what I was thinking.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In this instance, `#store > #shoppingCart{}` is a little useless, `#shoppingCart` should be unique, so you don't need to reference any parents or anything, which is what `>` essentially does.

[**Child Combinator or `>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)

`#a > #b` means a `b` element that is a child (but not a grandchild, and so on) of `a`, eg:

```
   <div id="a">
     <div id="b"></div>     // selects this element
   </div>
```

[**Adjacent Sibling Combinator or `+`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)

`#a + #b` means a `b` element that comes directly after `a` in the dom, eg:

```
   <div id="a"></div>
   <div id="b"></div>       // selects this element
```

[**General Sibling Combinator or `~`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)

`#a ~ #b` is similar to `+`, but it is any sibling after it in the dom, so the following could work:

```
   <div id="a"></div>
   <div>
     <a></a>
   </div>
   <div id="b"></div>       // selects this element
```

However, as for your question, you probably want something like this:

```
#store:hover ~ #shoppingCart {
  // mouse is hovered over #store and we want to affect a sibling
  // with id #shoppingCart that is "later" in the dom
}
```

More info on selectors can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Comment: Do note that for both `+` and `~`, the selection only works in a downstream manner, i.e. `#a + #b` only works when the HTML is `<div id="a" /><div id="b">` and not `<div id="b" /><div id="a">` ;)

Comment: Your first definition is a bit misleading - immediate or not, the child combinator selects a *child* of a given element.

Comment: @Adrift What word or phrase would you suggest?

Comment: None, just remove the word immediate.

Answer (score 0):

E > F -> Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.
E + F -> Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E.
E ~ F -> an F element preceded by an E element

You will find the full specification for CSS selectors here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Additional learning resource: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/

Comment: `E[foo~="warning"]` That's not a combinator. The latest specification can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors where you can find a `~` combinator.

Answer (score 0):

This is the link you are probably looking for:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Let's do a few examples:

```
#store > #shoppingCart {

   //code

}
```

This will select all elements that have the ID shopping cart and have a parent of ID store.

Another example:

```
p~ul {

    //code

}
```

Selects every ul element that are preceded by a p element